# How do i take a screenshot of a PDF using phantomjs and node?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I am new to phantomjs and node, so basically if i use the following code:

```
var webpage = require('webpage').create();

webpage.open('https://www.google.com/', function() {
      webpage.render('pdflala.png');
      phantom.exit();
});
```

I am able to get a screenshot of the webpage , but is there anyway that i can get a screenshot of a PDF using phantomjs ?

The below code if used to get a screenshot of a PDF will show a blank image.

```
var webpage = require('webpage').create();

webpage.open('https://www.link-assistant.com/pdf/SEO_in_2018.pdf', function() {
      webpage.render('pdflala.png');
      phantom.exit();
});
```

How do i take a screenshot of a PDF using phantomjs and node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phantomjs doesn't have a pdf rendering engine, it can save pages to pdf format, but it can't *render* pdf.

Your best bet is to use [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js), which has this capability, meaning that it can render the pdf to a HTML `canvas`.

You can then use `phantomjs` to take a screenshot of the canvas element.